# Pass notification data to the current activity instead of opening the Home?

Tags: android, android-activity, notifications, android-notifications

In my app I have a `HomeActivity` that is launching other activities, lets call one `SecondActivity`. Whenever a user selects a notification, I'm launching a `CommentsActivity`.

Whenever a notification arrives and the user taps on the banner or taps it in the Notificaiton Center, my `HomeActivity`'s `onNewIntent` method gets called, which launched my `CommentsActivity`. This is fine, except that I can't keep the back stack as it was before the user tapped the notification, meaning that if the user does

```
HomeActivity -> SecondActivity -> Taps Notification -> | Backstack is cleared and only HomeActivity remains -> CommentsActivity.
```

So when the user presses the back button, they are taken back home.

Is there a way to make my `SecondActivity`'s `onNewIntent` get called when a user opens a notification and they're already on the `SecondActivity`, instead of popping the back stack? The user flow I want is the following:

```
HomeActivity -> SecondActivity -> Taps Notification -> CommentsActivity (and backwards if the user presses the back button.
```

Keep in mind I'm using `android:launchMode="singleTask"` in my `AndroidManifest` for my `HomeActivity`, so I don't end up with multiple `HomeActivity` instances when a notification is tapped.

Comment: A little trick that might help. When user clicks on notification send new Intent to secondActivity and with that intent put some string. On second activity oncreate method check the string and if that's true just start a new intent to comment activity from second activity.

Comment: I thought of that hack, but when I'm saying SecondActivity, I might have 5 more activities in the back stack when the user opens a notification, which will all have to be recreated (along with their positions in RecyclerViews and data, which dosn't seem very do-able), so I was thinking if there is a way to make android not open the HomeActivity on each notificaiton tap, and let the currently running activity handle the Intent.

Answer (score 0):

**Solution**

You can use an activity that acts as an Activity router. When users launch the app (click app icon on the home screen or click on the notification), they will open this router activity, from here it will decide:

- If the first time users open the app (the `HomeActivity` does not exist in Back stack), then start the `HomeActivity`
- Otherwise, route the intent to the [onNewIntent(Intent)](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/Activity#onNewIntent(android.content.Intent)) of the current running activity (the activity at the top of the stack)

**Implementation**

**Step 1.** Create a class named `MyApp` that extends from the Application class. Its purpose is to listen to all activity lifecycle of the app.

```
public class MyApp extends Application {

    public static final String EXTRA_ORIGINAL_INTENT = "EXTRA_ORIGINAL_INTENT";

    private final ActivityLifecycleCallbacksImpl callbacks = new ActivityLifecycleCallbacksImpl();

    @Override
    public void onCreate() {
        super.onCreate();
        registerActivityLifecycleCallbacks(callbacks);
    }

    public boolean isHomeActivityStarted() {
        return callbacks.isHomeActivityStarted();
    }

    public void routeIntentToCurrentRunningActivity(Intent original) {
        Activity activity = callbacks.getCurrentRunningActivity();
        Intent intent = new Intent(this, activity.getClass());
        intent.putExtra(EXTRA_ORIGINAL_INTENT, original);
        // Call onNewIntent() method of the activity at top of the stack.
        intent.addFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TOP | Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_SINGLE_TOP);
        startActivity(intent);
    }

    private static final class ActivityLifecycleCallbacksImpl implements ActivityLifecycleCallbacks {
        public static final int INVALID_TASK_ID = -1;

        int homeActivityTaskId = INVALID_TASK_ID;
        Activity currentRunningActivity = null;

        @Override
        public void onActivityCreated(@NonNull Activity activity, @Nullable Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        }

        @Override
        public void onActivityStarted(@NonNull Activity activity) {
        }

        @Override
        public void onActivityResumed(@NonNull Activity activity) {
            if (activity instanceof RouterActivity) {
                return;
            }

            currentRunningActivity = activity;
            if (activity instanceof HomeActivity) {
                homeActivityTaskId = activity.getTaskId();
            }
        }

        @Override
        public void onActivityPaused(@NonNull Activity activity) {
        }

        @Override
        public void onActivityStopped(@NonNull Activity activity) {
        }

        @Override
        public void onActivitySaveInstanceState(@NonNull Activity activity, @NonNull Bundle outState) {
        }

        @Override
        public void onActivityDestroyed(@NonNull Activity activity) {
            if (activity instanceof RouterActivity) {
                return;
            }

            if (activity instanceof HomeActivity) {
                homeActivityTaskId = INVALID_TASK_ID;
            }
        }

        boolean isHomeActivityStarted() {
            return homeActivityTaskId != INVALID_TASK_ID;
        }

        @NonNull
        Activity getCurrentRunningActivity() {
            return currentRunningActivity;
        }
    }
}
```

Remember to add this class to the manifest file.

**Step 2.** Create a router activity named `RouterActivity`

```
public class RouterActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(@Nullable Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

        MyApp myApp = (MyApp) getApplication();
        if (!myApp.isHomeActivityStarted()) {
            Intent intent = new Intent(this, HomeActivity.class);
            intent.putExtras(getIntent());
            startActivity(intent);
        } else {
            myApp.routeIntentToCurrentRunningActivity(getIntent());
        }

        finish();
        overridePendingTransition(0, 0);
    }
}
```

**Step 3.** Add both classes into the manifest file

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    package="com.example.kotlinapp">

    <application
        android:name=".MyApp"
        android:allowBackup="true"
        android:icon="@mipmap/ic_launcher"
        android:label="@string/app_name"
        android:roundIcon="@mipmap/ic_launcher_round"
        android:supportsRtl="true"
        android:theme="@style/AppTheme">

        <activity android:name=".RouterActivity">
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />

                <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
            </intent-filter>
        </activity>
        <activity
            android:name=".HomeActivity"
            android:launchMode="singleTask" />
        <activity android:name=".SecondActivity" />
        <activity android:name=".CommentsActivity" />
    </application>
</manifest>
```